# How can one delete their Stack Exchange account for a certain network?

Tags: support

What are the steps to take in order to delete a stack exchange account for one network but keep your other networks? Also, I'm not sure where to ask this question but I must be close to the right place since this is not a religious question. Thanx.

Comment: Why would you want to delete your account? You can just stop using it.

Comment: @ashes999 If a user is not going to use his account, there's really no reason to have an account...

Comment: @Dynamic sometimes people make  emotional decisions that they regret later. There's no harm in leaving your account and coming back later (6 months? 12 months?) if you decide to use it again.

Comment: @ashes999 I cant see what Dynamic is saying, but to answer your question, I keep getting notifications from this network and its annoying. I'd rather not be bothered with an account here if I'm not going to use it. This is not a 'rash, emotional" decision, its an informed decision, as I do not want to be dragged into the drama of this network.

Comment: @ashes999 I agree that sometimes people make rash, emotional decisions. In fact, Dynamic has done just that, made rash emotional decisions to make comments here and regretted it and deleted them. :)

Comment: @Aliyah you are coming off as very rude and abrasive to others on the network. Please be polite and do not read into peoples intentions or draw unnecessary conclusions about others.

Comment: @ashes999 thats funny, people on this site come off as rude and abrasive towards me (im new here and was appalled at my first encounters) and I really want my account closed A.S.A.P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goto

https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/user-deletion

and follow the instructions.